# Using int.parse(string) in linq search doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, sdf

I'm using LINQ search in C#. One of my searches require converting a `string` to an `int`.
When I try to use `int.parse()` or `convert.toInt32()`, it displays an error (not recognized in LINQ)

for example:

```
var google = from p in ctx.dates
       where int.Parse(p.effDate) < 20101212 && int.Parse(p.effDate) > 20121212
           select p;
```

as you can see I have a string that contains my date in `yyyymmdd` format and I want to convert it to an integer so I can search between those date.

Comment: How can a date be before 2010 and after 2012? Do you have those dates mixed up?

Comment: u right it supposed to be  int.Parse(p.effDate) > 20101212 && int.Parse(p.effDate) < 20121212 .. but it doesnt change my question.

Answer (score 8):

The `yyyyMMdd` format has a nice property that the lexicographical ordering is the same as the chronological ordering so you can use string comparisons:

```
var google = from p in ctx.dates
             where p.effDate.CompareTo("20121212") < 0
             && p.effDate.CompareTo("20101212") > 0
             select p;
```

Comment: thank you for this quick answer. i've tried this but got an error says: "Error 18 Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'"

Comment: @Adir.el same as `p.effDate.CompareTo("20101212") < 0`

Comment: finaly i've found a decent answer :

                    google = from p in ctx.dates
                             where p.effDate.CompareTo(picker1) > 0 && p.effDate.CompareTo(picker2) <0
                             select p;

picker1 and picker2 are both strings in "yyyymmdd" 
thank you all for helping me

Answer (score 1):

As first you can't compare dates by just converting them to int, because it will fail in most cases. Parse your strings using `DateTime` `Parse` or `ParseExact` and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `int.Parse` is a client call, the Linq provider doesn't know how to map that to a database function.

Since the string is in an easily sorted format, you can use `where p.effDate < "20101212" && p.effDate > "20121212"`.

A better approach would be to change the database to store the dates in `date` columns not `char` or `varchar` columns.

Answer (score 0):

**finaly i've found a decent answer :**

```
 google = from p in ctx.dates
 where p.effDate.CompareTo(picker1) > 0 && p.effDate.CompareTo(picker2) <0 
select p;
```

picker1 and picker2 are both strings in "yyyymmdd" 
thank you all for helping me